# How do I approach variable with string value?

Tags: javascript

I like to pass parameter and want to use it to return specific variable

```
test1 (type) {
    const enable { color: 'blue' }
    const disabled { color: 'red' }
    return type === 'enable' ? enable : disabled
}
```

so for example, i like to change test1 to test2.
I want to do this because I have mulitple type and it makes code complicated.
Is there any way that i can do this?

```
test2 (type) {
    const enable { color: 'blue' }
    const disabled { color: 'red' }
    return type
}
```

Comment: You need `=` in a variable initialization: `const enable = {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Use an object keyed by the `type` value.

```
function test2(type) {
    const vals = {
        enable: { color: 'blue' },
        disable: { color: 'red' }
    };
    return vals[type];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like follows

```
test2 (type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'enable':
            return { color: 'blue' }
        case 'disabled':
            return { color: 'red' }
    }
}
```